# Ansible Syncronize Keeps failing with Permission denied

Tags: ssh, rsync, ansible-2.x

I have this simple Ansible setup:

- host_vars/testserver.yaml

  ```
  ---
  ansible_host: x.x.x.x
  ansible_connection: ssh
  ansible_port: 22
  ansible_ssh_user: ansible
  ansible_become: true
  ansible_become_user: root
  ansible_password: "PASSWORD HERE"
  ansible_ssh_pass: "PASSWORD HERE"
  ansible_sudo_pass: "PASSWORD HERE"
  ansible_become_pass: "PASSWORD HERE"
  hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  ```
- sync.yaml

  ```
  ---
  - hosts: all
     gather_facts: true

     tasks:
     - name: create a file (works)
       copy:
         dest: "/root/blah"
         content: |
           line 01
           line 02

     - name: copy app-scraper (fails!)
       synchronize:
         src: files/var/opt/app-scraper
         dest: /var/opt/
         rsync_opts:
           - "--exclude=.git"
           - "--exclude=__pycache__"
  ```

I keep getting `Permission denied (publickey,password)`. But other ansible builtins like copy, tempalte, unarchive, file, cron, ... work fine which shows user/pass is working. It is just `synchronize` that fails!!!

```
fatal: [lmoc1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "sshpass -d3 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o Port=22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='su -c rsync' -e \"ssh\" --exclude=.git --exclude=__pycache__ --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /home/leomoon/ansible/files/var/opt/app-scraper ansible@x.x.x.x:/var/opt/", "msg": "Permission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\ansible@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(703) [sender=3.2.3]\n", "rc": 5}
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Nobody knows what's going on?

Even if I add a copy task that would work fine but the syncronize would fail.

This OS has one user with key but I don't see why what would matter.

Comment: I updated above to include a copy task that works.

Comment: sshd_config is alsow set to `PasswordAuthentication yes` but still fails!

Comment: I have tried SO MANY things.

Ansible syncronize does not work if target host is using user/pass. It only works if target host is using user/ssh-key.

Nobody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's going on. In short, if you are re-assigning a variable, it will not be evaluated with Synchronize.

My setup is like this. Ansible will get the value of {{ ansible_pass }} from secrets.yaml and assigns it to all these variables...

```
ansible_password: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
ansible_sudo_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
```

This will work for all ansible modules except **Synchronize**.

## Test case

```
ansible/
    host_vars/
        testserver.yaml
    secrets.yaml
    sync_test.yaml
```

### host_vars/testserver.yaml

```
---
ansible_host: x.x.x.x
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_port: 22
ansible_ssh_user: ansible
ansible_become: true
ansible_become_user: root
ansible_password: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
ansible_sudo_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

### secrets.yaml

This has the ssh password here and it is encrypted. But for our test we can leave it not encrypted.

```
ansible_pass: PASSWORDHERE
```

### sync_test.yaml

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
    - secrets.yaml
  tasks:

  - debug: msg="{{ ansible_pass }} {{ ansible_password }} {{ ansible_ssh_pass }} {{ ansible_sudo_pass }} {{ ansible_become_pass }}"

  - name: create a file (works)
    copy:
      dest: "/tmp/blah"
      content: |
        line 01
        line 02

  - name: copy app-scraper (fails!)
    synchronize:
      src: flask/files/var/opt/app-scraper
      dest: /tmp/
      rsync_opts:
        - "--exclude=.git"
        - "--exclude=__pycache__"
```

And if you run this you can see the debug message is shwoing the correct password but it will fail at **synchronize**.

```
$ ansible-playbook sync_test.yaml -l testserver
Vault password: 

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [testserver] => {
    "msg": "PASSWORDHERE PASSWORDHERE PASSWORDHERE PASSWORDHERE PASSWORDHERE"
}

TASK [create a file (works)] ************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [copy app-scraper (fails!)] ********************************************
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "sshpass -d3 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o Port=22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u root rsync' --exclude=.git --exclude=__pycache__ --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /home/leomoon/ansible/flask/files/var/opt/app-scraper ansible@x.x.x.x:/tmp/", "msg": "Warning: Permanently added 'x.x.x.x' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\nansible@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(713) [sender=3.2.7]\n", "rc": 5}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
testserver                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

## Temporary fix

Ansible is not passing the password to Synchronize and this is a bug but the temporary fix is to **set_fact** those variables again! This was tested on ansible version 2.14.1:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.1]
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
```

So the sync_test.yaml should be changed to this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
    - secrets.yaml
  tasks:

  - debug: msg="{{ ansible_pass }} {{ ansible_password }} {{ ansible_ssh_pass }} {{ ansible_sudo_pass }} {{ ansible_become_pass }}"

  - name: create a file (works)
    copy:
      dest: "/tmp/blah"
      content: |
        line 01
        line 02

  - name: temp fix for synchronize to force evaluate variables!
    set_fact:
      ansible_password: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
      ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
      ansible_sudo_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"
      ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_pass }}"

  - name: rsync app-scraper (fixed!)
    synchronize:
      src: flask/files/var/opt/app-scraper
      dest: /tmp/
      rsync_opts:
        - "--exclude=.git"
        - "--exclude=__pycache__"
```

And this will work!